# change environment in Symfony framework?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I have put my project in Production server which is created in Symfony 1.4 and Propel as ORM. I am not able to access the site in Development environment(as i know it is in Production server). But i am not able to see error or bugs coming. Is there any way to access my site in Development enviornment?? I have Tried accessing the site by doing some change in the  "frontend_dev.php" file, but not good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible by Overriding the frontend_dev.php file's check.
i.e

```
/*if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', '::1')))
{
  die('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}*/
```

this worked for me. if any better solution please let me know.

Answer (score -2):

With Symfony 2.8.*, you have to change the .htaccess in the web folder : app.php to app_dev.php and work by default on a local server.

If you need to develop on a remote server, you can add your local IP adress to the ip list.